# Trying to right-size a critical loads subpanel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, solar

I'm installing solar and would like to set up a critical loads subpanel that is fed by both the solar and my main panel.  The microinvters in the kit are Enphase IQ8+.  I'd like to run a few circuits of lights and my ductless minisplits off of this subpanel.

From reading other questions on diy.SE, I know that I'll need to have the two sources of power feed into opposite ends of the bus bars and add stickers indicating that the breakers shouldn't be moved.

Eventually, I'd like to install the Enphase System Controller 3 between the main panel and the subpanel in order to have either daylight backup or battery backup.

Since the initial setup would have two sources feeding the panel, I think I need to size the bus bars so that they can't be overwhelmed if both sources are maxed out.  The solar system I'm installing is 33x of USNEA-SR-M660370HLP-370W for a combined ~12kW dc or ~10kW AC.  These will run through a combiner box before joining my load center.  I think that means my panels will max out at a bit under 50A supply, plus the 100A supply from my main panel.  Does that mean that my bus bars need to be rated for at least 150A?  I'd seen some answers talking about 705.12(b)(2) that says that with two sources at opposite ends of the busbar, 125% of the power sources must not exceed 120% of the busbar rating.  I think that would mean

```
125% * Inverter Breaker + Subpanel OCPD <= 120% * Busbar Rating
125% * 50A + 100A <= 120% * Busbar Rating
163 A <= 120% * Busbar Rating
136 A <= Busbar Rating
```

or the bus bar must be rated for around 136 - 140 A.

I'd originally been thinking the Siemens E1020MB1100FCGP would meet my needs but at this point I'm not sure.  From what I can tell, its busbars are rated for 100A so probably not sufficient.

I think the two main questions I have are:

1. Am I thinking about this correctly?  Is this the right figuring to determine sub panel capacity?
2. Is there a subpanel you'd recommend I use?  My main panel is Siemens so I'd been leaning that way but I'm not married to it.

The layout I have been considering is essentially:
[image]

Comment: Just get a 200 amp panel.  The rating of a panel is the maximum amps it can handle.  So feeding a 200 amp panel from 100 amps is perfectly okay.

Comment: "subpanel you'd recommend" shopping questions are opinion-based and off-topic, this is not a discussion forum

Comment: Can you get us the MCA of your minisplits please?

Comment: That's the Minimum Circuit Ampacity?  Looks like it's 21.9 amps.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt -- how many minisplits are we talking about here btw?

Comment: There are 3 indoor units (12kbtu, 9kbtu, 6kbtu), and one outdoor unit that they all connect to.